# Rails: How to get one model to "belong" to another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, polymorphic-associations

I have a model "votes" which belongs_to two models by polymorphous association, and has the attributes user_id and comment_id. Previously, I had a voting system in place for users that would create a new vote for a specific user every time a button was pressed:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @vote] do |f| %>
  <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="#{@user.id}" />
  <%= f.submit ": )", :onclick => 'alert("Voted up!")' %>
<% end %>
```

and `@user.votes.count` would return the number of times the button was pressed. However, I switched to a different method:

View:

```
<%= link_to "voteuser", vote_user_path(@user.id), method: :post, :class => "btn btn-small" %>
```

Controller:

```
def vote
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  Vote.create!(user_id: @user.id)
  redirect_to @user
end
```

Routes:

```
Website::Application.routes.draw do

  root 'home_page#home'
  get "votes/new"
  get 'users/random'
  post 'users/vote/:id' => 'users#vote', as: 'vote_user'
  get 'users/users/random' => 'users#random'
  resources :users
  get "all/allusers"
  get "all/users/new" => 'users#new'
  get 'all/all/allusers' => 'all#allusers'

end
```

and a Vote is still created, with a user_id equal to the current User.id, but now `@user.votes.count` returns 0, so the application isn't registering that the vote belongs to the user. How can I remedy this?

Vote Model:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Votes Schema:

```
create_table "votes", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "thing_id"
  t.integer  "comment_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "voteable_id"
  t.string   "voteable_type"
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, as: :voteable
end
```

User Schema:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "avatar_file_name"
  t.string   "avatar_content_type"
  t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
  t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
end
```

Comment: it should be @user.votes.count

Comment: @Kimooz Oh right, good catch. user.votes.count is how it is in my code.

Comment: Please, make sure that your line in routes comes before `users` resource, if there is one, and before `post 'users/:id'`... If not, then it will try to post to a user with id:`vote`...

Comment: Can you show the schema for those tables? Are you intending to vote for a user1 ? (without storing who voted)

Comment: @RubyRacer Yeah it does, I posted my entire Routes file.

Comment: I think you are missing the `voteable_type`, please show your votes schema.

Comment: @gmaliar I don't think so, I posted them above.

Comment: @mohameddiaa27 I posted them. Yes, all I want is to record that a particular user recieved a vote, with no additional information.

Comment: Do you want to store the user who votes for an object ?

Comment: @mohameddiaa27 No, just that a vote was cast.

Comment: Note that you don't need the `comment_id` and the `thing_id`. Because if you are storing only the object's vote, they can be saved in the polymorphic columns of voteable.

Comment: In my experience the word "polymorphic" is more common than "polymorphous".

Comment: @JaredBeck Thanks for letting me know, in the future I will use "polymorphic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `Vote.create!(voteable_id: params[:id], voteable_type: 'User')` for users or in short 
`Vote.create!(vote: User.find(params[:id])) # Vote.create!(vote: Comment.find(params[:id]))`

Comment: Shouldn't the hash key be `:voteable` as in `Vote.create!(voteable: User.find(params[:id]))`

Answer (score 0):

check if you retrieve the user id in your controller and you can in your view

```
<%= form_for [@user, @vote] do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: f.model.user.id %>
  <%= f.submit ": )", :onclick => 'alert("Voted up!")' %>
<% end %>
```

on your controller you can simply do:

```
def vote
  Vote.create!(user_id: params[:id])
  redirect_to @user
end
```

but you use the polymorphous association so you have to specify the user_id and the user_type.